# Is it possible to stop your MainActivity from being terminated?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am running into problems where if a user navigates through several child activities without returning to the `MainActivity` in between, when they press the back button it closes to the Android Home screen. I never call `finish()` on my MainActivity, it doesn't happen consistently, and not from the same screens. It happens when I have gone through many different Activities without returning to the `MainActivity`.

I'm assuming that the system is terminating the Activity while its in the background, but I'm not sure. Is there anyway to ensure that my parent activity doesn't get terminated?

I did not create the project. I'm aware that the navigation structure he used isn't right, but as of right now I'm not in the position to fix it.

Please do not tell me to do things a different way. I am asking only if there is a way to keep a particular activity from being terminated by the system.

Comment: Short answer from bazillion similar questions: NO

Comment: @Selvin Searched for the question several times the past few days and nothing that came up was related. If you would be interested in actually helping people on SO you could try to give a link to one of these questions next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not possible to stop your activity from being destroyed, you can check if there's no activities in the backstack, and restart your MainActivity when the back button is pressed in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put a handler in it that doesn't do anything besides giving itself another task (which is to give itself another task) every few seconds.